# Modify newly opened page after onClick event

Tags: javascript, onclick, window, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I am actually working on a `Greasemonkey`/`Tampermonkey` script that boils down to the following actions :

- stores data about a given page (let's say a wiki entry) : `Title`/`Author`/`Creation date`/`Additional links`
- from the said page, it adds a new link beside the title (for e.g.)
- on clicking the link, it would redirect to a form (a page on a different domain altogether) and paste the results in all the fields

What I can already achieve is :

- parse a `DOM` to get the required info (`document.getElement(s)By(Id|TagName|ClassName)`)
- store the data (using `sessionStorage.setItem`)
- retrieve the stored data (`sessionStorage.getItem`)
- add a link where I need in the page with an embedded `onClick` event that loads a new page (`window.open('url', '_blank')`
- log to console (`console.log`) or display a popup (`window.alert`) to help me debug

Unfortunately, once the new page is opened, all my attempts to modifiy the content proved moot. To debug, I tried opening a new page and, once opened, call `alert(document.getElementById('test').innerHTML)` but it always returned `null`, probably because the element designed by this ID doesn't exist on the 'old' page.

Can you point me in the right direction (if, of course, what I'm trying to achieve is even possible) ?

## Edit

I thought I could give a more concrete example :

- My GM script works on `https://apple.domain.com`
- When `https://apple.domain.com` is accessed, it adds a link next to every links in a list
- When I click on the new link (added by my GM script), it opens a new window/tab to `https://banana.domain.com` (same domain)
- Once on `https://banana.domain.com` (which is basically a form), the GM script fills in all the fields from the `https://apple.domain.com` web page (data stored using sessionStorage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I could not bypass the Cross-Domain issue between my two sites (falls into the XSS category I believe), I resolved it by using 2 specific GM/TM scripts :

- one for the `https://apple.domain.com` domain
- one for the `https://banana.domain.com` domain

When I'm done with the `https://apple.domain.com` domain, I just call the `https://banana.domain.com` domain with a custom URL including all my arguments as a parameter. That, way, once I am on the `https://banana.domain.com` domain, I just parse the URL and retrieve the desired arguments from it.